# I have an css 404 error with my website but the css exsits

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have question with `express`

**server.js**

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 8080

app.use(express.static('public'))
app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + 'public/css'))
app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + 'public/js'))
app.use('/img', express.static(__dirname + 'public/img'))

app.set('views', './views')
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

app.get('/signin', (req, res) => {
    res.render('signin')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('server is listening to port: 8080')
})

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.status(404);
  
    // respond with html page
    if (req.accepts('html')) {
      res.end('404 - Not Found');
      return;
    }
  
    // respond with json
    if (req.accepts('json')) {
      res.json({ error: 'Not found' });
      return;
    }
  });
```

**File structure**

```
public
    css
       signin.css
    img
    js
views
    signin.ejs
server.js
```

**signin.ejs**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../public/css/signin.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>works</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

**signin.css**

```css
body{
    color: yellow;
}
```

and the error is
[image: error_img]

```
http://localhost:8080/public/css/signin.css         [HTTP/1.1  404 Not Found 4ms]
```

Can someone help me?
What is the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can identify two issues.

First is that the code just concatenates `__dirname + 'public/css'`. The `__dirname` does not include a trailing slash, so if your path is `/home/foo`, you'll get a path like `/home/foopublic/css`. Use [`path.join()`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_join_paths) instead.

Second, the HTML appears to refer to the CSS file relative to the location of the HTML on your disk. As there is already a handler for the path `/css` set which serves files from the css directory on your disk, the correct path would be `/css/signin.css` instead of `../public/css/signin.css`.

So, on the node.js side:

```
const path = require('path')

app.use('/css', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/css')))
app.use('/js', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/js')))
app.use('/img', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/img')))
```

Although you don't really even need these, as there `app.use(express.static('public'))` middleware already serves the files and directories from the `public` directory.

And the HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/signin.css">
```